# Flutter Compress Camera Image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-image

I want to click the photo through camera and want to compress it and then upload it to the server

i have included the Image Compress Dependency its Showing me the error **The getter 'absolute' isn't defined for the type 'PickedFile'.**

written the code of Clicking photo and uploading it to server
// Taking Photo From Camera

```
Widget bottomSheet() {
return Container(
  height: 100.0,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 20,
    vertical: 20,
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        "Take A Picture",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
          onPressed: () {
            takePhoto(ImageSource.camera);
          },
          label: Text("Camera"),
        ),
      ])
    ],
  ),
);
}

void takePhoto(source) async {
final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(
  source: source,
);
setState(() {
  _imageFile = pickedFile;
});
await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(
  _imageFile.absolute.path,
  minWidth: 2300,
  minHeight: 1500,
  quality: 94,
  rotate: 90,
);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile just add imageQuality in the _picker.getImage

```
_picker.getImage(
      source:ImageSource.camera,
      minWidth: 2300,
      minHeight: 1500,
      imageQuality: 75
)
```

As with the image quality value size of the image get changed

Comment: but suppose I would like to send image over internet to API, its better to have it in tiff and compressed.

Comment: Yes, you can post the image that get with image quality. Since every multipart api has the size restriction to post.